# Save multiple data from different database to one database

Tags: c#, sql

[image: here is the dummy program]how can I save data from different databases into one database (`MainDatabase`)?

I just want to have an idea making a simple program that can retrieve data from multiple databases with the SAME table name e.g `transactionTBL`, and then save it to one database with the same columns and value. btw I did tried using a stored procedure - but it have to be an object not varchar or string.

```
@DATABASE varchar(50)

INSERT INTO UserControlTenant.dbo.tenantData (tenant_name, receipt_id, amount, date, time)
    SELECT * 
    FROM ___.dbo.transactiondata
```

Example:

Database1

```
~transactiontbl~

ID
receiptID
amount
date time
```

Database2

```
~transactiontbl~

ID
receiptID
amount
date time
```

-
MainDB

```
~transactiontbl~

ID
receiptID
amount
date time
```

Comment: I think `Database1` and `Database2` should be Linked with `MainDB` to access!

Comment: Nope.. the project is intended to be dynamic, like calling a multiple counter and gets is total sales and put it in one database (MainDB).. something like that..

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic? You can link databases and write Procedure on Database side for merging data. And you can execute your procedure on c#

Comment: I already did that it went well but in other cases like . cant put a string to an object
                                                                                @DATABASENAME varchar(50)
  
AS


insert into UserControlTenant.dbo.tenantData 
(tenant_name, receipt_id , amount, date, time)
 select * from [@DATABASENAME].dbo.transactiondata

Comment: btw Thanks... I got some ideas from now.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need database link in order to be able to access one database from another database.

```
INSERT INTO UserControlTenant.dbo.tenantData (tenant_name, receipt_id, amount, date, time)
    SELECT * from OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,'SELECT * FROM xxx.dbo.transactiondata');
```

or if it is mssql DB

```
INSERT INTO UserControlTenant.dbo.tenantData (tenant_name, receipt_id, amount, date, time)
    SELECT * from [SRVR002\ACCTG].dbo.transactiondata');
```

for creating database link check [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: wooahh!! thats new for me... Thanks for helping a rookie here.. is that T-SQL? btw thanks